# Extension 'cogs.commands' raised an error: TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Tags: python

SO I am trying for days now to make my cogs work but always seem to run into an error.
This time I am getting the `Extension 'cogs.commands' raised an error: TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'` error.

My code for this would be so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what is in your cogs.commands file?

Comment: Please add an reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In my commands file there are all the commands I use and an on_ready event when I start the program ```@Bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await Bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
        print('I am ready!')```

To reproduce the error just use the code above and have a second file with the on_ready event shown above this text and I added and the bottom of the commands. py the add_cog code. 
```def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(commands(bot))```